# How to add external jars in/with Maven WITHOUT installing locally

Tags: spring, maven, maven-dependency-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin, maven-dependency

Currently the way I'm referencing my Jars through my Spring Boot application is by using Maven dependency manager with a system path.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>example1.1</groupId>
        <artifactId>example1.1</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/example1.1.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

... etc (30 more jars)
```

How would one avoid this way of loading of jars since I'm moving over to to publishing it as a jar and getting a error of:

> should not point at files within the project directory,
>   ${basedir}/libs/example1.1.jar will be unresolvable by dependent
>   projects

Any easy way to load multiple jars without putting them on the local system?

Cheers

Comment: Usually, you reference jars from a Maven repository. If these are standard external components, you will find them in MavenCentral. Inside a company, you usually set up your own Maven repository as a server. This manages the external and internal artifacts.

Comment: @JFMeier yeah that seems to be the answer I keep seeing. Thanks for the quick response. `Inside a company, you usually set up your own Maven repository as a server.` this is probably the way I'm going to have to do it.